# Output not coming out as expected when calling methods from other classes

Tags: java

I am attempting to create output that looks like the following:

```
Here's the first production worker.
Name: John Smith
Employee Number: 123-A
Hire Date: 11-15-2005
Shift: Day
Hourly Pay Rate: $23.50
```

However my code results in:

```
Here's the first production worker.
Name:
Employee Number: INVALID EMPLOYEE NUMBER
Hire Date:
Shift: Day
Hourly Pay Rate: $23.5
```

Here are the methods and code that i have used

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Employee em = new Employee();
    ProductionWorker pw= new ProductionWorker();

    // First Worker (Testing setting all methods and to string methods)

    System.out.print("Here's the first production worker.");
    pw.setAll("John Smith", "123-A","11-15-2005",1,23.50);
    System.out.print(em.toString());
    System.out.println(pw.toString());
```

```
public class Employee{
  private String emName="";
  private String emID="";
  private String emDate="";
  private boolean isIDValid(String ID)
  {
    boolean status = true;
    if (ID.length() != 5)
    {
      status = false;
      emID="";
    }
    else
    {
      if ((!Character.isDigit(ID.charAt(0)))  ||
        (!Character.isDigit(ID.charAt(1)))  ||
        (!Character.isDigit(ID.charAt(2)))  ||
        (ID.charAt(3) != '-')               ||
        (!Character.isLetter(ID.charAt(4))))
        {
            status = false;
            emID="";
        }
    }
    return status;
  } 
  public void setName(String name)
  {
    emName=name;
  }
  public void setID(String ID)
  {
    emID=ID;
  }
  public void setDate(String date)
  {
    emDate=date;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    System.out.println(emName);
    if (isIDValid(emID))
    {
      return "Name: " + emName + "\nEmployee Number: " + emID + "\nHire Date: " + emDate;
    }
    else
    {
      return "Name: " + emName + "\nEmployee Number: " + "INVALID EMPLOYEE NUMBER" + "\nHire Date: " + emDate;
    }
  }
```

```
public class ProductionWorker extends Employee{
  private int emShift;
  private double emPay;
  Employee employee = new Employee();
  public void setAll(String name,String ID,String date,int shift, double pay)
  {
    employee.setName(name);
    employee.setID(ID);
    employee.setDate(date);
    emShift=shift;
    emPay=pay;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    if ((emShift != 1) && (emShift != 2))
    {
      return "Shift: INVALID SHIFT NUMBER" + "\nHourly Pay Rate: $" + emPay;
    }
    if (emShift==1)
    {
      return  "\nShift: Day" + "\nHourly Pay Rate: $" + emPay;
    }
    else
    {
      return "\nShift: Night" + "\nHourly Pay Rate: $" + emPay;
    }
  }
```

It seems that the emName emDate and emID variables are not transerring into into the em.toString method. However I have tested if the variables are being set by testing and printing them into the console within the setter methods. Somewhere between the employee setter methods and the employee toString method the program loses the value of the variable. Please help.

Comment: You never set the emName, emDate, or emID variables for the Employee object, you have only set them for the ProductionWorker object. The Employee object does not know the implementation of its child class.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is wrong. You are making the assumption that the variable

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

inside your `ProductionWorker` class is somehow connected to the one you declare in the `Main` class.

```
Employee em = new Employee();
ProductionWorker pw= new ProductionWorker();

pw.setAll("John Smith", "123-A","11-15-2005",1,23.50);
System.out.print(em.toString());
System.out.println(pw.toString());
```

In this code, you actually end up with 2 instances of `Employee`. One called `em` and "stored" inside of Main and the other inside of the `ProductionWorker` instance `pw` called `employee`. These are 2 separate and disconnected instances.

If you fix that, then you will be fine. For instance, add a getter() method to grab the instance of `Employee` inside of your `ProductionWorker`.

## Updated Code

The `Employee` class does not change.

### ProductionWorker

Add a getter (`getEmployee()`) method.

```
package eu.webfarmr.employee;

public class ProductionWorker extends Employee {
    private int emShift;
    private double emPay;
    Employee employee = new Employee();

    public void setAll(String name, String ID, String date, int shift, double pay) {
        this.employee.setName(name);
        this.employee.setID(ID);
        this.employee.setDate(date);
        this.emShift = shift;
        this.emPay = pay;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if ((this.emShift != 1) && (this.emShift != 2)) {
            return "Shift: INVALID SHIFT NUMBER" + "\nHourly Pay Rate: $" + this.emPay;
        }
        if (this.emShift == 1) {
            return "\nShift: Day" + "\nHourly Pay Rate: $" + this.emPay;
        } else {
            return "\nShift: Night" + "\nHourly Pay Rate: $" + this.emPay;
        }
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return this.employee;
    }
}
```

### The Main class

Remove the local instantiation of `Employee` and call the getter on the `ProductionWorker` instead.

```
package eu.webfarmr.employee;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductionWorker pw = new ProductionWorker();

        // First Worker (Testing setting all methods and to string methods)

        System.out.print("Here's the first production worker.");
        pw.setAll("John Smith", "123-A", "11-15-2005", 1, 23.50);
        System.out.print(pw.getEmployee().toString());
        System.out.println(pw.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but how would it be possible to create a getter method to grab the instance of Employee?

Comment: For example, using a public function getEmployeeName  that returns a String, which will be the name of a given object instance.

Comment: Is there a way i can reword Employee em = new Employee() to access a already created instance instead of creating a new one?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the sample code. You should be good to go now.